# Syncing entire SD card makes phone hot/unresponsive

Tags: sync, ssh, ftp, lagging

- Samsung Galaxy S Relay
- Android 4.4.4
- Cyanogenmod 11

I've tried many different solutions to sync my phone's SD cards with a computer over Wi-Fi, leaving them to run overnight because there's so much data (~30 GB), but in the morning the phone is slow and unresponsive, warm to the touch, apps like Gentle Alarm don't work, etc.  It becomes so slow that when I try to use it, it eventually stops responding completely and reboots itself.  I've tried:

- FolderSync
- Syncthing
- Samba on phone
- FTP server on phone
- SSHDroid on phone and SyncBack on computer
- iDrive Backup

At first I assumed it was because the apps were flawed, so I tried different solutions, but since it happens with all of them, it seems it's a more fundamental OS problem, like accessing too many files at a time or sending too much data over the network causes the phone to become unstable?  Maybe a memory leak or it opens files and never closes them or something?  How can I diagnose this and make it workable?  When I look at CPU/memory usage, it seems normal?  (Though it reboots while I'm trying to check, so a CPU/memory usage logger would be better.)

Comment: Continuous data read and write in massive amount uses a good amount of CPU and greater the spikes in CPU the greater the heat it would generate. Try using a kernel or an app which can set the CPU at a specific (low or moderate) frequency. It would affect the read/write speed but overheating would remain under control. I've a related answer here: [High CPU load during file copy to SD card](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110664)

Comment: @Firelord Ok, but why would the phone continue to have problems after the sync has been stopped?  I would guess that phones automatically throttle their CPU when they're overheating, but it probably depends on manufacturer?

Comment: Throttling  depends upon the kernel and then on the chipset. Mainly kernel controls the state of CPU. And *you're forgetting that you're using a nightly build*. Are you aware of this question: [Recommendation for questions pertaining to a problem specific to a nightly build of a ROM](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2077)

Comment: @Firelord It's not related to the nightly build; I've been trying this off and on with different solutions for months, including before I started using the nightly

Comment: How do you know it is not? But if you know it is not the OS then you would've already found the cause by now.  // The kernel you're using comes from a nightly build. // The solutions you've noted here doesn't seem to contradict my claim.

Comment: I know it's not related to the nightly build because it's been happening since **before I started using the nightly build**, as I said above.   Thanks for arbitrarily closing my question because it had a particular word in it.

Comment: There are some testings that I need to know if you're comfortable with it: does this happen if you *don't* use the apps at all? Have you tried syncing some files *on internal storage* and see if this occurs? I have a hunch it's a problem with syncing external storage to cloud. Also, are there many small files, or only some big files? How often you sync it?

Comment: @AndrewT. "does this happen if you don't use the apps at all" No.  " tried syncing some files on internal storage"  I believe it happened with that, too, but I'll check.  There are many small files.  It happens during the first attempt at syncing, so it's transferring the entire card.

Comment: @AndrewT. Full sync of 1 GB / 27,000 files from internal "/sdcard" had no problems, so you might be right that it's specifically related to the external SD.  do you have a theory for why?

Comment: I still don't have any conclusion (hardware is not my strength), but I think it might be related to SD card read speed, the device memory, or the network speed. Probably there's a bottleneck between reading the file while syncing, which make it fail, but due to retry policy, the app still tries to sync it (and probably memory leak due to it), overheating the WiFi/device... or the SD card "temporarily died" due to extensive read while the app syncs. Unfortunately I can only provide one theory, which based on my experience, but I can't certainly answer it.

Comment: I've removed some of my comments  since the post has been reopened by community and they would have only confused new readers when left intact.

Comment: Argh this happened again. I installed iDrive Backup, and in the morning my alarm didn't go off because Gentle Alarm had been killed.  Other apps would open but then would lock up when trying to access files?  I rebooted and it said "Rebooting..." forever and didn't actually do anything until I held down the power button.  So it's not any particular app, just something about trying to back up lots of files.

Comment: @endolith:  How hot is the phone?  For what it's worth, certain apps can tell you the battery temperature (with help from the thermistor built into every Android phone battery).  Also, other apps can tell you the [CPU temperature](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yanyan.cputemp&hl=en).  Please [edit] your question and enlighten us.  Also, you can use some external device to measure the phone's external temperature.  Maybe a thermal imaging camera?